# Brand New UE5 C++ Project Won't Build With No Errors

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine5

In every instance where I've created an Unreal Engine 5.1 project with C++ and build the default project, it pops up with these errors.

[image]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1835   attribute "deprecated" does not apply here  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\Serialization\BulkData.h    283 
Error (active)  E1835   attribute "deprecated" does not apply here  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\Serialization\BulkData.h    1239    
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   381 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   382 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   383 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   384 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   409 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   410 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   411 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Public\UObject\CoreNet.h   412 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Serialization\ArchiveProxy.h   49  
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Serialization\ArchiveProxy.h   55  
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Serialization\ArchiveProxy.h   61  
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Serialization\ArchiveProxy.h   67  
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Serialization\ArchiveProxy.h   73  
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Serialization\ArchiveProxy.h   162 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "FRHIViewableResource" is undefined  Learning    C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Source\Runtime\RHI\Public\RHI.h   2233    
Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.1\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" LearningEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\miche\OneDrive\Documents\Unreal Projects\Learning\Learning.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.   Learning    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets    44
```

There's really not much else to say besides the default C++ project does not compile.

I've downloaded:

- Unreal Engine 5.1
- Visual Studio C++

Perhaps there is something additional to download?

I'm on an Asus TUF Gaming a15 laptop running Windows 11.

What could make this compile correctly?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  All code and error should be in the question as formatted text; click the [Output] tab.

Comment: Can you give some more details about how you're compiling this? Apparently some sort of Visual Studio. Which version? Did you follow the steps [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/setting-up-visual-studio-development-environment-for-cplusplus-projects-in-unreal-engine/) to make sure you have all the required components?

Comment: I'm just right clicking the solution file and "Build". I followed every instruction in the article you gave me still with no luck

Comment: If you are in specific need of a source build you could download 5.1 from the Epic Games Launcher

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're building via Visual Studio instead of Unreal Engine Editor and in the UE Editor you have live coding enabled. If you press CTRL+ALT+F11 the UE Editor - code will compile.

If you want to do the compiling via Visual Studio, turn live code off (in fact i've found it to be problematic so i leave it off a lot as if it crashes and you have a component added to a character for example the UE crashes, removing the links etc to that component - which is ergh)

Comment: It is very strange. Yesterday I had the exact problem, then I installed some kind of plugin that VS suggested and it worked fine. I could compile from VS and also from UE live code. I open up the project today and I get same BS errors in VS, but live code still works.

Comment: I can mix and match live code and VS build as much as I want. Neither is throwing errors.

Comment: I am new to UE5. "Live Coding" was turned on by default. And CTRL+ALT+F11 does NOTHING in 5.2.1